# Django Python Delete Project App Library

Tags: python, django

If I want to delete a Django App or Project. 
Is there a way to cleanly delete it?

Or a library in Python? How can I delete and re install libraries.

So I am SURE that nothing is left of that library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to delete some python library go to /site-packages or /dist-packages, find this module(single file) or package(directory) or egg file (look at the extension) and delete this.

If you want to delete an app and you have it inside your project, simply delete app directory, remove it from settings and remove all references to objects from this app.

Comment: Thanks! And there is nothing else I need to do? Just delete folders?

Comment: Well, installing a module is simply copying python file to a place, where it will be found by python, so I believe this should be enough.